# How to work with Android Beacon

Tags: android, ibeacon

I have tried [this](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html),
I am able to scan all devices but not able to calculate major and minor using Android core classes.

I have tried this

```
public class TagBluetooth {

private Context context;
private List uuidList;
private iTagBle iTagble;
private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;
private final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 101;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler handler;
// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback;
private List list;


public TagBluetooth(iTagBle activity){
    this.context= (Context) activity;
    iTagble=activity;
}


public TagBluetooth(iTagBle activity,List list){
    this.context= (Context) activity;
    iTagble=activity;
    uuidList=list;
}

/**
 * initialize ble component
 */
public void initialize(){

    if (isBLEAvailable()) {
        bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        handler = new Handler();

        leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                iTagble.onScanComplete(device,rssi,scanRecord);
            }
        };

    }

    checkBluetoothStatus();
}

/**
 * Ensures Bluetooth is available on the device and it is enabled. If not,
 * displays a dialog requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth.
 *
 * @return true for device bluetooth available and false for bluetooth not available
 */
private void checkBluetoothStatus() {

    if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        context.startActivity(enableBtIntent);

    }
}


/**
 * ebale and disable ble devices scanning
 *
 * @param enable
 */

public void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

    if(!isBLEAvailable())
        return;

    if (enable) {

        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
    }
}




/**
 * Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device. Then
 * you can selectively disable BLE-related features.
 *
 * @return true for BLE support and false for BLE unsupported
 */
private boolean isBLEAvailable() {

    if (!context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        iTagble.showMessage("BLE not supported");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Requirement:

1. scan all beacon devices (including different manufacturer).
2. Track entry and exit from beacon.
3. Minor and Major ranging.
4. Scan device even application is closed.

If any one help me on this, it wold be grate for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean.. If you have answer then give otherwise leave it .

Comment: You're member of SO since last `2 years, 11 months` and you don't know the rules of SO. Plz take a look [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @M D Now give your answer

Comment: See my first comment. You still dont understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use Kontakt API from [here](https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-beacon-admin-sample-app). But you can't major exact entry and exit time from any API. See [here](http://docs.kontakt.io/android-sdk/quickstart/).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But that is for a specific vendor. I want to it should work for all vendors.

Comment: Use Estimote sdk. It is work for all vendor. I got the list of all near by beacons using this api.

https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK

Comment: I have integrated Estimote SDK. It monitor region for different vendor but it does not give no. of devices in a region.

Comment: @dmkrush, you should check your code and study the API. It gives every information about the devices which in his region. I have implemented this and got the list of all beacons.